# How to copy a Set<Set<Integer>> into a List<Integer[]> in Java?

Tags: java, list, collections, set

I want to copy a `Set<Set<Integer>>` of array to a List of Integer[]. I want to do that because I want to change the first element of every array when it is 0 , and put it at the end.

I have manage to do that  but in a List<Set> , and when looping throw , I can't make changes because the array are still a Set.

No other questions make this clear, instead they explained when we have only `Set<SomeWrapperClass>`

Maybe some other solutions? Remark: I cannot change the `Set<Set<Integer>>`

My Set:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> indexs = new HashSet<>();
```

I can convert to a List only in this way:

```
List<Set<Integer>> arrangedIndexOfCourses = new ArrayList<>();

 static Set<Set<Integer>> coursesIndex = Sets.powerSet(Sets.newHashSet(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0));
  static List<Set<Integer>> arrangedIndexOfCourses = new ArrayList<>();
```

The following method return all the occurence of unique numbers made from 0123456789 ( Guava library )

```
 private void indexSet(Set<Set<Integer>> coursesIndex) {
        Set<Set<Integer>> indexs = new HashSet<>();
        for (Set<Integer> token : coursesIndex) {
            indexs.add(token);
            arrangedIndexOfCourses.add(token);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

And the code where I tried to change the first 0 of the arrays and put at last:

```
  for (Set<Integer> i : arrangedIndexOfCourses) {
                if (i.contains(0)) {
                   Collections.rotate(arrangedIndexOfCourses, -1);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You say arrays but there is no single array in your code. Also, please show a concrete example with some toy data, some example numbers.

Comment: You should also consider that HashSet does not guarantee any order when iterating its contents. So strictly seaking a HashSet does not have a "first element".

Comment: @Zabuzard , done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, the main trick in this task is how to implement rotation of the first element if it is 0.

As mentioned in the comments, not all types of sets maintain order and therefore have a "first" element.  But upon converting a set to stream, even for a `HashSet` there's a first element in the stream unless it's empty.

Therefore, the set of integer sets may be converted to a list of integer arrays as follows:

1. Take the first element of the stream using `limit` or `findFirst`
2. Compare to 0, if needed put it to the end
3. Else keep the stream of the set as is

```java
Set<Set<Integer>> data = Set.of(
    Collections.emptySet(),
    new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3)),
    new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6)),
    new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(10, 0, 100, 1000)),
    new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(25, 0, 1, 16, 4, 9)),
    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(0, 5, 50))
);
      
List<Integer[]> rotatedZeros = data
    .stream()
    .map(s -> 
        (s.stream().findFirst().orElse(-1) == 0 // or limit(1).findAny()
            ? Stream.concat(s.stream().skip(1), Stream.of(0))
            : s.stream())
        .toArray(Integer[]::new)
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

rotatedZeros.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[]
[4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[10, 0, 100, 1000]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 0]
[50, 5, 0]
```

Comment: I don’t think that this inner operation benefits from using the Stream API. Compare with `List<Integer[]> rotatedZeros = data .stream() .map(s -> { Integer[] a = s.toArray(Integer[]::new); if(a.length > 0 && a[0] == 0) Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(a), -1); return a; }) .collect(Collectors.toList());` This even has a meaningful result if the source sets are unordered (it doesn’t guaranty a result order then, but does guaranty a non-zero first element if the array size is not exactly one).

Comment: @Holger, that's a really interesting version!  Minor enhancement: rotation should be applied `if (a.length > 1 && a[0] == 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

*the 2-step solution with a lambda w/o external library*

(1) convert the `Set<Set<Integer>>` to a `List<Integer[]>`

```
List<Integer[]> arrangedIndexOfCourses = coursesIndex.stream()
    .map(s -> s.toArray(Integer[]::new)).collect(toList());
```

(2) iterate over the arrays and change the *zero-arrays* in the traditional way

```
for (Integer[] indices : arrangedIndexOfCourses) {
  if (indices.length > 0 && indices[0] == 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length - 1; i++)
      indices[i] = indices[i + 1];
    indices[indices.length - 1] = 0;
  }
}
```

---

*a lambda based on Alex's mind blowing solution*
moving the zero-rotating-stuff upstream makes the lambda less *trickier* and You can work with collections instead of arrays

```
List<Integer[]> arrangedIndexOfCourses = coursesIndex.stream()
    .map(s -> {
      if (s.stream().findFirst().orElse(-1) == 0) {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.addAll(s);
        l.remove(0);
        l.add(0);
        return l.toArray(Integer[]::new);
      } else
        return s.toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }).collect(toList());
```